# DownloadManager vs Background service

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have the requirement of downloading several images and videos and the requirement entails "one time" download so there isn't really any caching required and that's why I am not using Volley. Volley for videos could be expensive.

Next, I stumbled upon built-in Android's [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) which seems to facilitate downloads on a queue, the API doesn't seem bad overall but I was wondering how it might compare to using a `Service` with a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`(*an option dictated by one of the Commonsware's post*)?

**Note:** My use case is strictly **not** that of downloading images for a grid with chances of repeated requests. My requests have to be single time downloads only. The request may be a mix of few images and videos.

Could the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` inside `Service` be significantly faster?

Comment: do you need your service to be public or private? DM is public downloader, so it might not fit you needs, but it's fast to implement. ThreadPoolExecutor just manipulates threads, so you will download with HttpClient inside a thread. Service is good, but if you need guaranteed delivery - you should take a look at JobScheduler(or SyncAdapter).

Comment: @ViktorYakunin : Well, do you have anything for private? I mean, public would be fine in my requirement but it would be good to know if there is something for private.

Comment: recently I found this library, that might fit your needs (https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader). And of course your own implementation (Service, IntentService, JobScheduler) will work in the way you want

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Adding a new library is again not a bad idea but this will add to the APK size.

Answer (score 8):

> I was wondering how [`DownloadManager`] might compare to using a `Service` with a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`

`DownloadManager` does not require your process to be running, and it handles all of the issues with retry policies and so forth. On the other hand, `DownloadManager`:

- Requires that the download be initiated from a simple URL (i.e., no session cookies)
- Shows the user the results via the Downloads app
- Can only easily download to external storage
- Downloads one item at a time
- May delay the download start for a while (e.g., if something else is being downloaded)

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is unlikely to be part of an in-process solution, though a `ThreadPoolExecutor` might. That would only be necessary if you needed to try downloading N videos at a time and you didn't want to use any multi-threading option offered by your HTTP client API (e.g., OkHttp). Since you want to download these things in the background (presumably), and you do not know what the user is doing in the foreground, I recommend only downloading one video at a time, so you do not make it difficult for the user to use the Internet from whatever is going on in the foreground.

> Could the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor inside Service be significantly faster?

You are comparing apples and asteroids.

Neither `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` nor `Service` perform HTTP downloads. An in-process HTTP client API (`HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp, Volley, etc.) performs HTTP downloads, as do some out-of-process options (notably `DownloadManager`).
A proper comparison would be between `DownloadManager` and the combination of:

- An in-process HTTP client API, and
- Some form of service, to allow the download to go on even if the user navigates away from your UI

From a pure speed standpoint, any HTTP client API will be limited by the network and so should perform roughly equivalently. Volley is not well-suited for large downloads because it puts the entire result in memory, and you don't have heap space for a video. Other options will let you stream the results to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing I didn't mention is that it is likely in my use case that user is interacting with my App's Activities in the foreground meanwhile. Would your answer change because if this?

Comment: @pulp_fiction: Probably not, only because "likely" != "guaranteed". Videos tend to be large and may take quite a while to download. The user may even turn off their screen while the download is still going on. Hence, if you are using an in-process solution, you will want some form of `Service` (probably a regular `Service` but with `startForeground()`). Or, use `DownloadManager`.

Comment: "Shows the user the results via the Downloads app" - this can be disabled with `setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)`